# Function Returns Different Values in Different Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cross-browser

I made a function which returns selected css properties of an element in an array. However this array differs in Chrome and Firefox. 
fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9Jyx8/1/

This is the function:

```
function butunCSSyiAl (el,ozellikler) {
    var deger = new Array();
    for (var i = 0 ; i < ozellikler.length ; i++) {
        deger[i] = el.css(ozellikler[i]);
        if(ozellikler[i] == "width"){
        //alert(el.css(ozellikler[i]));
        }
    }
    return deger;
}



 var ozellikler = new Array('font-size','font-weight','font-style','color','text-transform','text-decoration','letter-spacing','word-spacing',  'line-height','text-align','vertical-align','direction','background-color','background-image','background-repeat','background-position','background-attachment','width','height','top','right','bottom','left','margin-top','margin-right','margin-bottom','margin-left','padding-top','padding-right','padding-bottom','padding-left','border-top-width','border-right-width','border-bottom-width','border-left-width','border-top-color','border-right-color','border-bottom-color','border-left-color','border-top-style','border-right-style','border-bottom-style','border-left-style','position','display','visibility','overflow-x','overflow-y','white-space','clip','float','clear','cursor','list-style-image');
```

Are there any ways to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers set their own default styles, so your array will have different values between different browsers. Each browser may have a different default for `font-size`, margins, etc.

Comment: So I should avoid trying to get default values. Thanks.

Comment: That's correct. As @adeneo said in the comments, you can use a CSS reset (search Google or this site for how to do this; there are lots of examples). Otherwise, the default values will never be consistent, so your array will not be consistent, either. 

If this was helpful to you, please remember to accept it as the answer! :)